# How do I add a string array property to a composite index?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

According to the CosmosDB docs only scalar values can be added to a composite index. How about an array of scalar values? Like an array of strings?

I have tried this in the Azure portal with no luck (saving it results in an error) (where "id" is a scalar (int) and "tg" is an array of strings):

```json
        [
            {
                "path": "/id",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/tg/[]",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
```

When I use PopulateIndexMetrics it gives this recommendation, yet I can't figure out how to add the composite index.

Comment: This isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

For composite index CosmosDB doesn't support array wildcard (e.i "path": "/tg/[]"), but it does support specific array indexer like

```
  [
        {
            "path": "/id",
            "order": "ascending"
        },
        {
            "path": "/tg/[]/property",
            "order": "ascending"
        }
 ]
```